# Executing a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, classpath

I have one query , I have P: drive in my system and it contains a folder name DeviceJars which contain different jars and one of jar name pinpadservice.jar is inside it.

Now I am trying to run a batch file named pinpadservice.bat and the pinpadservice.bat contains

```
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -cp p:\DeviceJars\PinpadService.jar main/PinpadServiceMain
```

But rite now I am trying to execute it through command window but it is not executing  please advise do I need to set the classpath for it like..

set `CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\DeviceJars\pinpadservice.jar` and then tring to execut the batch file

Comment: What exactly does *not executing* mean? What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the CLASSPATH in the script; don't depend on any environment variable.  Add *all* the JARs your app needs into the -cp value, separated by semi-colons.

All Java EE IDEs and app servers ignore CLASSPATH environment variables.  I don't set it that way on any machine that I work on.